# add drag and drop field for web form

Tags: webforms, dropzone.js

I am currently working with Drupal 8.5.6x version and I need to add a drag and drop field to the web form. I have downloaded the web form dropzonejs. But it didn't work. Any idea how can I implement drag and drop field for my form?

Comment: Hey - dilshika, when you say you have downloaded dropzone.js can you clarify how you have incorporated it into your drupal site? It would be useful to see the html for this. Have you added dropzone to your page?

Comment: Yes I have added it to my webform page and it worked fine with administrator but it is not working with anonymous users.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the html code you have added to your page? And any other relevant code/changes you'e made. This will help others understand your issue.

Comment: Actually, I removed it now. My mentor said it's development version so It's better to avoid. And I didn't use any HTML.